# Help needed in solving a system of DE

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The system of DE is:
$$\frac{dI}{db}=-\frac{b}{c}\frac{dJ}{db}-\frac{2ab+1}{2c}J$$
$$\frac{dJ}{db}=\frac{b}{c}\frac{dI}{db}-\frac{2ab-1}{2c}I$$

Assume that $a$ and $c$ are constants and both $I$ and $J$ tends to zero as $b$ tends to $\infty$.

---

To be honest, I have never solved a system of DE before. I usually use W|A if I am in a situation like this but in this case, even W|A fails. I am not sure if it is even possible to solve the above system.

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing mixed derivative terms is possible by inserting the second equation's $dJ/db$ into the first equation and vice versa:
$$
\frac{dI}{db} = -\frac{b^2}{c^2} \frac{dI}{db} + 
\frac{b}{c}\frac{2ab-1}{2c} I -
\frac{2ab+1}{2c} J \\
\frac{dJ}{db} = -\frac{b^2}{c^2} \frac{dJ}{db} -
\frac{2ab-1}{2c} I -
\frac{b}{c}\frac{2ab+1}{2c} J
$$

rearranging gives two coupled equations
$$
\frac{dI}{db} + 
\left(-\frac{c^2}{c^2+b^2}\frac{b}{c}\frac{2ab-1}{2c}\right) I = 
\left(-\frac{c^2}{c^2+b^2}\frac{2ab+1}{2c}\right) J \quad (*) \\
\frac{dJ}{db} +
\left(\frac{c^2}{c^2+b^2}\frac{b}{c}\frac{2ab+1}{2c}\right) J =
\left(-\frac{c^2}{c^2+b^2}\frac{2ab-1}{2c}\right) I \quad (**)
$$

which one can turn into a vector equation:
$$
\frac{d}{db}
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
I \\
J
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\alpha & \beta \\
\gamma & \delta
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
I \\
J
\end{array}
\right]
$$

with the matrix
$$
A =
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\alpha & \beta \\
\gamma & \delta
\end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{b}{c^2+b^2} \frac{2ab-1}{2} & 
\frac{c}{c^2+b^2} \frac{2ab+1}{2} \\
-\frac{c}{c^2+b^2} \frac{2ab-1}{2} &
-\frac{b}{c^2+b^2} \frac{2ab+1}{2}
\end{array}
\right]
$$

This is now cast into a form like it is used for dynamical systems, there could be useful tools to get more analytic information.

A graph of the directional vector field would be nice now, with stationary points etc.

#### The case $a = c = 1$

Here the matrix reduces to
$$
A =
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{b}{1+b^2} \frac{2b-1}{2} & 
\frac{1}{1+b^2} \frac{2b+1}{2} \\
-\frac{1}{1+b^2} \frac{2b-1}{2} &
-\frac{b}{1+b^2} \frac{2b+1}{2}
\end{array}
\right]
$$

This is the given candidate for $I$:
$$
I^c(b) = 
\frac{e^{-\sqrt{1 + b^2}}}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}\sqrt{b + \sqrt{b^2+1}}}
$$

with derivative
$$
\frac{dI^c}{db}(b) =
-\frac{e^{-\sqrt{1+b^2}} 
\left(2 b^3 + \left(2 \sqrt{1+b^2} + 3 \right) b^2 +
\left(3 \sqrt{1+b^2}+2\right) b + 1 \right)}
{2 (1 + b^2)^{3/2} \left(\sqrt{1+b^2}+ b \right)^{3/2}}
$$

from equation $(*)$ we get
$$
J^c(b) = \frac{2(1+b^2)}{2b+1}\left(
-\frac{e^{-\sqrt{1+b^2}} 
\left(2 b^3 + \left(2 \sqrt{1+b^2} + 3 \right) b^2 +
\left(3 \sqrt{1+b^2}+2\right) b + 1 \right)}
{2 (1 + b^2)^{3/2} \left(\sqrt{1+b^2}+ b \right)^{3/2}}
- \frac{2(1+b^2)}{b(2b-1)}
\frac{e^{-\sqrt{1 + b^2}}}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}\sqrt{b + \sqrt{b^2+1}}}
\right)
$$

Comment: And then?  This is a good start, so +1, but due the presence of the independent variable $b$ in the coefficients, following through may be tricky!

Comment: For now I don't know how to proceed analytically. Resorting to numerics or approximation of the matrix by a constant matrix ($b \to 0)$ and performing the exponential matrix ansatz. Or using series for the unknowns $I$ and $J$, will have to sleep over it.

Comment: Well, so far so good, I've got a couple ideas meself, if anything pans out I'll get back to y'all.

Comment: Thanks mvw! I don't think I understand any of it but is it possible to find the solution for $I$? I am not very much concerned about $J$ currently. I really had a feel that it would be difficult to solve this system. I appreciate your help so far. :)

Comment: Also, can you please let me know if the system yields the following solution for $I$ when $a=c=1$? $$\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\exp(-\sqrt{1+b^2})}{\sqrt{1+b^2}\sqrt{b+\sqrt{b^2+1}}}$$

Comment: Ok, a candidate for a solution helps. I can use it for a better explanation too.

Comment: @mvw: I don't really like that method of solving the problems but if it is really too difficult to solve the system, I think I should drop the problem. This problem cropped out of another problem I was trying to solve: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818494/integral-int-0-infty-frac-sqrt-sqrt-alpha2x2-alpha-exp-big-bet , I came up with the above system of DE but was really unsure whether it is correct or not because of my inexperience in solving the system of DEs. Looks like this DE method is no good too. :( Anyways, thank you once again for all the help. :)

Comment: No problem, this is just error prone work, better done by a computer algebra system. Solving a differential equation is kind of a more general integration, so I would have not expected the job to get easier in your case. And you get lots of solutions so more conditions to pin down a single solution would be necessary. I thought you got the system by some physical relationship. How did you derive the equations from that problem?

Comment: @mvw: I considered $I$ as the given integral in that thread. And then I considered another integral $J$ defined as:
$$J(b)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}+a}e^{-b\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}\cos(cx)\,dx$$
To derive the system of DEs, I differentiated $I$ wrt $b$ and then applied integration by parts on resulting integral. I got integrals equal to $dJ/db$ and $J$. I did a similar thing with $J$ and arrived at the system I posted. This looked really awkward to me initially because I never tried this kind of method before for solving integrals.

Comment: With $$I(b) = \int\limits_0^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}-a}\,e^{-b\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}\sin(cx)\,dx$$ my first step would result in $$\frac{dI}{db} = -\int\limits_0^{\infty}\sqrt{a^2+x^2}\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}-a}\,e^{-b\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}\sin(cx)\,dx$$ and I am not able to derive your differential equations from this on.

Comment: @mvw: I am posting my working as an image due to the character limit. http://i57.tinypic.com/10fq05y.png