# Integral: $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-ab\cosh x}\cos\left(ac\sinh(x)+\frac{ix}{2}\right)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to solve this:
$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-ab\cosh x}\cos\left(ac\sinh x+\frac{ix}{2}\right)\,dx$$

---

I don't have much ideas about the problem. I thought of writing $\cos x=\dfrac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$ but couldn't proceed after that.

$$\Large \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty} \left(e^{ -(ab\cosh x-iac \sinh x)-\frac{x}{2}}+e^{ -(ab\cosh x+iac \sinh x)+\frac{x}{2}}\right)\,dx$$

$\displaystyle 
\begin{aligned}
ab\cosh x-iac\sinh x &=a\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}\cos(ix)-\frac{c}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}\sin(ix)\right)\\
&=a\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\sin\left(\alpha-ix\right)\\
\end{aligned}$

Similarly,

$\displaystyle 
\begin{aligned}
ab\cosh x+iac\sinh x &=a\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}\cos(ix)+\frac{c}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}\sin(ix)\right)\\
&=a\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\sin\left(\alpha+ix\right)\\
\end{aligned}$

where $\alpha=\arcsin\left(\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}\right)$

So the integral can be simplified to:

$$\Large \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty} \left(e^{-a\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\sin\left(\alpha-ix\right)-\frac{x}{2}}+e^{-a\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\sin\left(\alpha+ix\right)+\frac{x}{2}}\right)\,dx$$

A solution without using contour integration is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: By the looks of it, [Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) seem to be the way to go.

Comment: @Lucian: I am not sure how to use that here. Can you please post a solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Using parity properties, the integral can be rewritten as
   $$I=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ab\cosh x+iac\sinh x-\frac{x}{2}}dx$$
2. Note that $b\cosh x-ic\sinh x=\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\cosh\left(x-i\phi\right)$ with 
   $$\cos\phi=\frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}},\qquad\sin\phi=\frac{c}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}.$$ Hence, shifting $x$ by $i\phi$ [for that we need to assume that $\phi\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$], we obtain
   $$I=\frac{e^{-i\phi/2}}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\cosh x-\frac{x}{2}}dx$$
3. The last integral can be expressed in terms of the [Macdonald function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) $K_{\nu}(r)$, which has [integral representation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E9)
   $$K_{\nu}(r)=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-r\cosh x\pm\nu x}dx.$$
   In addition, for $\nu=\frac12$ this function [reduces to an elementary one](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.39.E2): 
   $\displaystyle K_{1/2}(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2x}}e^{-x}$.

Therefore the final result is
$$\boxed{\displaystyle I= 
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2a\sqrt{b^2+c^2}}}\;\exp\left\{-a\sqrt{b^2+c^2}-\frac{i}2\arctan\frac{c}{b}\right\}}$$

Comment: Hello O.L.! Very nice answer as always! :) Can you please explain why the following holds true: $$\int_{-\infty-i\phi/2}^{\infty-i\phi/2} e^{-a\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\cosh x-\frac{x}{2}}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-a\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\cosh x-\frac{x}{2}}dx$$.

Comment: Also, can you please provide some reference for the Macdonald function? Thanks! :)

Comment: Sorry for the triple comment. This problem cropped out from this problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818494/integral-int-0-infty-frac-sqrt-sqrt-alpha2x2-alpha-exp-big-bet . The integral mentioned in the linked thread is the imaginary part of the problem discussed here but considering the imaginary part of the final answer gives a sign error. :(

Comment: @PranavArora Unfortunately to answer your first question properly, one does need some complex analysis (deforming the contour of integration does not change the value of the integral provided we do not cross singularities of the integrand). Some info about Macdonald function can be found at [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) and the integral representation I'm using is the formula 10.32.9 [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32)

Comment: Ah ok but thanks for the references, I will look at them soon. Can you please see my third comment? The original integral in the linked thread can be reduced to the following definite integral using the substitution $x=\alpha \sinh t$.
$$\sqrt{2}\alpha^{3/2}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ab\cosh t}\sin(ac\sinh t)\sinh\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)\,dt=\sqrt{2}\alpha^{3/2}\Im\left(\int_0^{\infty}e^{-ab\cosh t}\cos\left(ac\sinh t+\frac{it}{2}\right)\,dt \right)$$ 
But taking the imaginary part of your final answer gives a sign error. :(

Comment: @PranavArora The identity from your last comment misses a sign, since $$\frac{\cos(a+ib)-\cos(a-ib)}{2}=-i\sin a \sinh b$$

Comment: Oops, I have been doing that sign error from a week. Really silly of me. :P BTW, can you also post the same answer to the linked thread? Thank you once again, I will soon give the bounty to your answer when the system lets me. :)

Comment: That's fine, if you have some issues with that asker, I won't post a link to this thread there. :) Really got to learn a lot from your answer.

Comment: @PranavArora Please feel free to post there anything you want. I just don't want to participate there myself :)

Comment: I just made a solution there and linked to this thread. :) Finally, the problem is solved, I was banging my head on this one from days.