# Huygens-Fresnel principle

Tags: integration

The math derivation of Huygens principle in 2D, applied to a plane wavefront propagation, gives the following field complex amplitude at a distance "d" of the initial wavefront (the unit for distances is the wavelength):

[integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9VTQ.png)

Numerical integration gives the expected value (pure delay operator):

[pure delay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yjtx.png)

But Mathematica(r) fails to derive a close form solution to the above integrale.
Does anybody know a way to derive it?

Comment: Are you sure these expressions are correct? They don't match in the limit as $d\rightarrow 0$, for instance.

Comment: Hi John, Add the hypothesis d>0. The case d=0 is no issue since it corresponds to the initial wavefront that is known by definition. Regards

Comment: I think there's a larger problem, though. When I use Mathematica to numerically evaluate the two given expressions at $d=0.1$, I get $0.773678 - 0.264512 i$ for the first, and $0.809017 - 0.587785 i$ for the second. They do not match. Furthermore, if I make the substitution $u = x/d$, the first integral becomes $\exp(i \pi/4) \sqrt{d} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} du \exp\left(-i 2\pi d \sqrt{1+u^2}\right)/{(1+u^2)}^{3/4}$, which goes to 0 as $d\rightarrow 0$, whereas $\exp(-i 2\pi d)$ goes to 1.

Comment: You are right. There is a discrepancy at low values of d betwen the expected value (pure delay) and the formula that I derived from Huygens-Fresnel principle.

Comment: It means that my model contains some approximation. Its rational:

Comment: 2D => space attenuation is as the square root of the distance; obliquity attenuation is the cosine of the incident/diffracted ray angle.

Answer (score 0):

Given the discussion in the comments above, I now realize that the equality between these two expressions is an approximate one expected to hold only when $d$ is large. In the large-$d$ limit, this integral can be evaluated using the [stationary phase approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_phase_approximation).

We start by making the change of variables $x = u\, d$, which causes the integral to become
\begin{equation}
I(d) \;=\;
e^{i \pi/4} \sqrt{d}\, \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}du \;
\frac{e^{-i\, 2\,\pi\, d\, \sqrt{1+u^2}}}{({1+u^2)}^{3/4}}\, .
\end{equation}
The stationary phase approximation asserts that when $d$ is large, so that the oscillatory portion of the integral oscillates very rapidly, the value of the integral is dominated by the region where the derivative of the phase function $2\,\pi\, d\, \sqrt{1+u^2}$ is zero. This occurs at $u = 0$. Near $u=0$ we have
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{1+u^2} \thickapprox 1 + \frac{1}{2}u^2
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{({1+u^2)}^{3/4}} \thickapprox 1 ,
\end{equation}
and the integral becomes
\begin{align}
I(d) &\thickapprox
e^{i \pi/4} \sqrt{d}\, e^{-i\, 2\,\pi\, d}\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}du \;
e^{-i\, \pi\, d\, u^2}\\
&= e^{i \pi/4} \sqrt{d}\, e^{-i\, 2\,\pi\, d}\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{i d}}\\
&= e^{-i\, 2\,\pi\, d}\, ,
\end{align}
which is the desired result. (Note that $e^{i \pi/4} = \sqrt{i}$.)

By the way, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1642129/conjecture-int-0-inftydx-fracei-alpha-sqrtx21-sqrtx21j-1qx) that I asked a while ago is related, and comes from a consideration of the Huygens-Fresnel principle in 3D.

Comment: This is great, thanks !  So no close form solution for the integral without approximation ?

Comment: No closed form so far as I'm aware. By making the change of variables $u = \sinh\,t$ you can get it into the form $\sqrt{i d}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dt \exp(-i 2\pi d \cosh\,t) / \sqrt{\cosh\, t}$. I had hoped this might turn into some sort of modified Bessel function in $d$, but the $\sqrt{\cosh\, t}$ seems to prevent this.